# Inserting a javascript variable that is a mathjax command into a html page that outputs formatted maths

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have a variable in javascript that depends on an input from

```
<input type="text" id="inputfunction" value="">
<button onclick="example">Example</button>
<p id="input"></p>
```

In the js script I have used `document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = inpt;` to place this variable on the page.

The variable comes out similar to say '3x+8' however I want this to be formatted with mathjax. To facilitate this I currently have

```
  <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Stylesheet1.css'/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script type="text/javascript" async
                src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
        </script>
    </head>
```

in my html document, however this doesn't output the variable formatted. I have tried using `document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = \\(inpt\\);` or placing `$$` on either side of it however this just puts it on the page as `\(inpt\)` or `$$inpt$$`. Is there any way to have it so that mathjax formats the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I eventually found it and it was a really easy fix. I just added

`MathJax.Hub.Typeset();`

at the end of the function and that makes MathJax look back over the page to format anything else. Apparently you shouldn't call this directly though because MathJax may be performing other actions so to counteract any issues this may cause you can write

`MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);`

which makes sure MathJax has finished all other processes before typesetting the page stop any synchronisation errors.